# Error al crear migraciones con seeders con laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

Hola comunidad tengo un problema al momento de crear las migraciones con los seeders realmente solo son tres tablas: user, grades y ciclos; no hay problema cuando hice las migraciones con la tabla user y grades pero cuando hice el modelo, la migración el factory y el seeder de Ciclo me muestra el siguiente error cuando hago las migraciones:

Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

Target class [Database\Seeders\Ciclo] does not exist.

Estos son mis archivos

**Migración de Ciclo**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

class CreateCiclosTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('ciclos', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->id();
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('ciclos');
    }
}
```

**Factory de Ciclo**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;
use App\Models\Ciclo;

class CicloFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = Ciclo::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->word(10)
        ];
    }
}
```

**Seeder de Ciclo**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\Ciclo;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class CicloSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        Ciclo::create([
            'name' => '2021'
        ]);
    }
}
```

He revisado incluso he repetido intentando cambiar los tipos de datos por si es algo con los datos pero no logro encontrar el problema, yo soy muy novato en Laravel, muchas gracias por solo leer y sobre todo muchas gracias por apoyar, saludos.

También adjunto el modelo de Ciclo pero a este no le he hecho cambios

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Ciclo extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
}
```

Comment: En que momento lanza ese error? Cuando corres algún comando? Cual? Y que tienes en la clase DatabaseSeeder? Probaste agregar el campo name a la propiedad fillable del modelo?

Comment: Hola gracias por tu respuesta, el error ocurre cuando ejecuto el comando: php artisan migrante:fresh --seed. Ahora lo del fillable dónde debería colocarlo?

Comment: Probablemente estés intentando usar la clase Ciclo en alguna clase dentro del namespace Database\Seeders sin importarla. Por eso te preguntaba por la clase DatabaseSeeder

Comment: Hola muchas gracias ya encontré el error y como tu mi indicaste el problema estaba en el databaseseeder, en vez de hacer el call CicloSeeder solo estaba escribiendo Ciclo sin el Seeder; muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

He logrado resolver el problema y como indicaba [porloscerros Ψ](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/92278/porloscerros-%CE%A8) mi problema estaba en el DatabaseSeeder.php ya que lo tenía de loa siguiente forma:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Seed the application's database.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        $this->call(UserSeeder::class);
        $this->call(Ciclo::class);
    }
}
```

Esta línea es incorecta

```
$this->call(Ciclo::class);
```

Y debe ser

```
$this->call(CicloSeeder::class);
```